# How can i solve "[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "@layouts//Header" from "pages\Group\index.tsx". Does the file exist?"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

First, please know that I am not good at English
I am going to build my first project. I use react + ts + Vite.
I want to add Head components from other routes but i cant....

In App.tsx, going to /login or another route works fine, but an error occurs in the part where you go to /group and call the header.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuOhO.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhKWt.png)

These are my Code.

vite.config.js

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgrPlugin(),tsconfigPaths()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  resolve: {
  },
});
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "types": ["vite/client", "vite-plugin-svgr/client"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@layouts/*": ["layouts/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@typings/*": ["typings/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
  },
  "include": ["src",]
}
```

App.tsx

```
import { Routes ,Route,Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import loadable from "@loadable/component";


const LogIn=loadable(()=> import('@pages/Login'));
// const SignUp =loadable(()=> import('@pages/SignUp'));
const Group = loadable(()=>import('@pages/Group'));
const MyChat = loadable(()=>import('@pages/MyChat'));
const MyProfile = loadable(()=>import('@pages/MyProfile'));
const Private = loadable(()=>import('@pages/Private'));


function App() {
    console.log("APP");

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
        <Route path = '/login' element={<LogIn/>}/>
        {/*<Route path = '/signUp' element={<SignUp/>}/>*/}
        <Route path = '/group' element={<Group/>}/>
        <Route path = '/mychat' element={<MyChat/>}/>
        <Route path = '/myprofile' element={<MyProfile/>}/>
        <Route path = '/private' element={<Private/>}/>
    </Routes>

  )
}

export default App
```

/layouts/Header/index.tsx

```
import { FC } from "react";

const Header:FC =()=>{
  console.log("header!!")
    return(
        <h1>
            header!
        </h1>
    )
};


export default Header;
```

/pages/Group/index.tsx

```
import Header from "@layouts/Header";

const Group =()=>{

    return(
        <>
            <Header></Header>
            <h1>groupChat</h1>
        </>
    )
}

export default Group;
```

I already checked the route issue.

Comment: Please post the code the code and error as text, not a screenshot.